This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly. error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\.venv\Lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\__main__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import __version__, config, ui, validation  # noqa: E402
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\.venv\Lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\ui.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import config, dialogs, packaging, utils
  File "C:\.venv\Lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\dialogs.py", line 26, in <module>
    root = Tk()
  File "C:\Users\hwimalarathne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2459, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    C:/Users/hwimalarathne/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/hwimalarathne/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/hwimalarathne/AppData/Local/Programs/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/hwimalarathne/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/library C:/Users/hwimalarathne/AppData/Local/Programs/library C:/Users/hwimalarathne/AppData/Local/Programs/tcl8.6.14/library C:/Users/hwimalarathne/AppData/Local/tcl8.6.14/library
 
This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

How could you fix this error.

Reinstall it? If it still doesn't work, give more details... [ask] and [mre]

It is a bug on Python 3.13.0 when virtual environment is used.
